# Fast switch rise time techniques

Tags: mosfet, high-voltage, pulse, rise-time

This question is continuation of this question: [High Frequency Square Wave Generator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/521326/high-frequency-square-wave-generator)

I am trying to drive a 400V supply and 50ohm load with an RF MOSFET which has a rise time of 3-4 ns and fall time of 10 ns.

I need to have fall and rise time no more than 2ns (2ns fall 2ns rise).

Since the voltage is high I couldn't find any MOSFET that fast.

Is there a MOSFET which is capable of reaching this speed, or should I seek another solution for this?

Thanks to comments I am looking for Vacuum Tubes right now. It would be nice if someone suggest me resource about how to select fast rise time vacuum tube.

Duty cycle and frequency are not very important. 50 kHz might be enough. I just need fast rise and fall time.

Comment: Well, what is the limiting factor in your switching speed? Gate capacitance?

Comment: cascode driven would eliminate any Miller contribution, but 2 ns is still fast for bipolar or FET at that voltage. What about thermionics?

Comment: Is this actually a continuation of yesterday's question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/521326/high-frequency-square-wave-generator ?

Comment: @Brian Drummond yes actually it is. Should I refere my previous question? If yes, I will edit.

Comment: I think so. You're giving a bit more information (any answer yesterday would ignore the new voltage requirement for example) but still not enough. We still have no idea what load impedance you are switching 400V in 2ns to; or what current you are expecting to switch. Spoiler : if there is more than an inch of wire or PCB trace involved, its inductance is about to make your life interesting.

Comment: @Neil_UK I don't have a clue about thermionics.

Comment: @Ismail Thermionics means vacuum tubes in case you did not know

Comment: @Andrew Morton Load is 50 ohm I edited the question. I am searching for vacuum tubes right now. But don't know how to select them or if they are fast enough.

Comment: 50 ohms? So, 8 Amps, you're trying to switch 3.2 kilowatts at 2ns rise time? Hmmm ... good luck.