# Fast rise time reed relay

Tags: relay, high-voltage, switching, pulse, rise-time

I am currently working on a project related that I asked before [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/521454/fast-switch-rise-time-techniques). The purpose is to have 2ns rise time 30ns pulse width at 250V (with 50ohm load). Repetition is 30hz.

I tried avalanche transistor ZTX415 and I don't know why it didn't work. I will look at it another time. While I was searching, I saw [this research](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231136043_High-speed_switching_in_particulate_magnetic_recording_media). I am going to try a similar one but I am not sure how they done it. I have 1kV reed relays. But none of these relays are rated for nanoseconds rise or fall times. **I didn't quite understand how this relay have that much short rise time. In datasheet it says operate time is several milisecons**

Coax cable is storing voltage and after triggering the field coil it discharges trough it to 50ohm load. Is it important to choose a fast driver to switch relay? I tried this circuit with 300pF capacitors  (instead of coax) and 250V. But rise time is about 6-7 ns. **What can I use to decrease rise time. Is length of oscilloscope probe and speed of driver important?**

Btw I didn't use 50ohm environment. Does it effect rise time?

[Here datasheet of relay I used](https://cdn.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/611527_852386.pdf)
Here is the circuit:

[image]

Comment: Reed relays are mechanical so they will have a mechanical response time. They will have a **switching time** or changeover time, not a "rise time". Did you measure the coil inductance and resistance to calculate the current time constant? (\$ \tau = \frac L R \$.) This will give you a rough idea of how long it will take for the current to rise enough to switch the contact.

Comment: Look up pulse forming network. That's what your bit of coax is doing. The speed of the relay drive wants to be crisp, but that is not setting your rise time. You should not be using a scope probe but connected as 50 \$\Omega\$ perhaps thru a load or attenuator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-forming_network

Comment: You *do need* a 50 ohm load (@ oscilloscope input). It can be connected to the switch with 50 ohm coax. Note that if you want a 250V pulse amplitude across the 50 ohm oscilloscope load, you'll need to charge the left-hand coax line to 500V through that large-value non-inductive resistor. I've used this arrangement with an avalanche switch (to get 100V pulse) of 100ns duration.

Comment: @glen_geek What was the rise time for 100V pulse? I tried avalanche switch but something went wrong I don't know. I couldn't even get the output pulse ( I used ZTX415 at 220V -260V).

Comment: Rise/fall time was approx 1ns with a TIP29 power transistor. It avalanches at a DC supply considerably higher than data sheet. But the disadvantage is that you have no control of pulse height - depends entirely on the transistor you select. Have never tried a reed switch at these high voltages.